# I want to generate a bundle file at the physical location while running the React app using Webpack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have tried a lot of things, but it didn't work. I know when we will run the React application it will create a bundle file in the memory instead of a physical location, but is it possible to create in the physical location?

The bundle file should be created at the physical location and updating at the same time while starting the React application.